# Related Posts loop - offset

Tags: loop, tags, offsets, recent-posts

I've been working on this for many, many, many weeks already. I've already asked similar questions here and elsewhere, but nobody seems to be able to sovle this problem.
Maybe it's not possible anyways?

My related posts are tag based and the code looks like this:

```
<?php 
                        $backup = $post;
                        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                        if ($tags) {
                            $tag_ids = array();
                            foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;

                            $args=array(
                                'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                                'showposts'=>4, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
                                'caller_get_posts'=>1
                            );
                            $my_query = new wp_query($args);
                            if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                                while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
                                    $my_query->the_post();
                                ?>
```

I want users to be able to scroll to the next 4 related posts after that, and again to the next 4. A total of 12 posts. I'm using jQuery Tools' Scrollable to do so.

Each loop will sit between divs so that scrollable will where to cut the content and where to scroll.

All I could find about offsetting your loop was this:

```
   // FIRST LOOP: display posts 1 thru 4
<?php query_posts('showposts=4'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=4&offset=0'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count1 = 0; if ($count1 == "4") { break; } else { ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php $count1++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>


// SECOND LOOP: display posts 5 thru 8
<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=4&offset=4'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count2 = 0; if ($count2 == "4") { break; } else { ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php $count2++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>


// THIRD LOOP: display posts 9 thru 12
<?php query_posts('showposts=4'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=4&offset=8'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count3 = 0; if ($count3 == "4") { break; } else { ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php $count3++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I tried, but keep getting error messages. 
Basically I just have no clue how to combine my original code with that one.

Or is there a more elegant solution?

**EDIT: UPDATE October 17th**

The code basically works, there's only ONE HUGE PROBLEM. It now produces the same related posts in every single entry, even in posts that don't even have any tags!! 
Also, it messes up the comments, too! It doesn't display the correct number of comments and shows the pingbacks of another post instead. Any idea why?

```
<h2>Related Posts</h2>                      

<!-- "previous page" action -->
<a class="prev browse left"></a>

<?php
 $args=array(
'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'showposts'=>12, // get all the posts at once, then split them up afterwards.
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
 );

$posts_per_block = 4;

$my_query = new wp_query($args); ?>

<!-- root element for scrollable -->
<div class="scrollable" id=chained>   

    <!-- root element for the items -->
    <div class="items">

<?php
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
if ( ($my_query->current_post) == 0 ) {
    echo '<div>';
}
elseif ( ( $my_query->current_post ) % $posts_per_block == 0 ) {
    echo '</div><div>'; //close and open a new div every nth post
}
elseif ( ( $my_query->current_post + 1) == ( $my_query->post_count ) ) {
    echo '</div>'; //close the div if you run out of posts
} ?>

<div class="relatedPosts"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(120,80)); ?></a>
<div class="relatedPosts_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div></div>


<?php
endwhile; endif;
?>

    </div>

</div>

<!-- "next page" action -->
<a class="next browse right"></a>
```

I really hope that finally somebody can help me figure this out.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please include actual error messages you are getting. Also `query_posts()` should not be used for creating multiple loops - I'd clean that up because you are unlikely to get answers about complicated issues with code that is not using loops properly.

Comment: That's what I thought anyways, so I tried to avoid using "query_posts" until now. Thanks, it seems that we're getting closer to solve the problem (see my updated question). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to display three blocks of four related posts, and flip between the three blocks using scrollable?

If so, does the below help (not tested)? Assuming scrollable needs its content in separate divs, you could do something like this. It should produce a containing div with up to three divs inside, each containing 4 posts... assuming you have 12 posts to display. if not it should die gracefully without leaving any divs hanging open.

```
<?php
 $args=array(
'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'showposts'=>12, // get all the posts at once, then split them up afterwards.
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
 );

$posts_per_block = 4;

$my_query = new wp_query($args); ?>

<div id="scroller-wrapper">

<?php
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
if ( ($my_query->current_post) == 0 ) {
    echo '<div class="scroller-block">';
}
    else if ( ( $my_query->current_post ) % $posts_per_block == 0 ) {
    echo '</div><div class="scroller-block">'; //close and open a new div every     nth post
}
the_title();
the_content(); //any other post stuff here

if ( ( $my_query->current_post + 1) == ( $my_query->post_count ) ) {
    echo '</div>'; //close the div if you run out of posts
}
endwhile; endif;
?>

</div>
```

**NB** You're using some deprecated code in your example, eg 'caller_get_posts' and wp_start() - you should use 'ignore_sticky_posts' and the_post() respectively.

**EDIT**: moved the closing of the internal divs to after, not before the post content. oops

Comment: Yes, yes! You got it :) Your code seems to work. Awesome! There's only one little issue. I need to replace "the_title" and "the_content" with what I want to be displayed, but I have this within php tags and so now I the syntax error message: syntax error, unexpected '<'. I know what I have to do, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I updated my question, could you please have a quick look at the code? Thanks so much!! :)

Comment: Good! When mixing up HTML with php, you need to close the <?php ?> tag first. eg `<?php the_title(); ?><p>This is plain HTML<?php echo " with some PHP"; ?></p><?php the_content(); ?>`. Does that make sense? Alternatively you could stay in PHP and echo out the HTML like so: `<?php echo "<p>I am inside some PHP tags</p>"; ?>`

Comment: Awesome, I got it to work. Thanks so much! I tried to get this to work for so long, so you have NO IDEA how much you helped me out!!! :) :)

Comment: Oops, I was happy too early it seems. Actually now it produces the EXACT same related post for EVERY SINGLE entry, even if a post doesn't have any tags it shows related posts. Any idea why? See my updated question for the updated code.

Comment: are you still including the code that was populating the $tag_ids array, ie `  $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                        if ($tags) {
                            $tag_ids = array();
                            foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;`

Comment: Uhm, no. Just as I posted the code in my update. If I were to put the code snippet you mention back in where exactly would that go then (without causing any syntax errors)?

Comment: It can go anywhere before the $tag_ids variable is required, and as long as it's enclosed in php tags it's ok :). Try this: [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/Mi193tvV)?

Comment: Hello. I tried it, but it's causing the exact problem as before. Here's my complete single.php - maybe something else is interfering? http://pastebin.com/CY1sEKfh

Comment: The tags seem to populate ok on my test install so i'm not sure about that... however, the comment problem is caused by running one loop inside another - WP needs to be reminded where its content is coming from or it will pull the comments from one of the related posts. easily fixed: just add `<?php wp_reset_query() ?>` after closing the if($tags) (line 128 on what you pasted). If you wanted to hide the 'related posts' header when there are no tags, you could move it into the if($tags). NB this won't prevent a post with a _unique_ tag showing the section, but you could fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much. This stopped causing the comment count issue. However, the actual loop for the related post doesn't work. It shows the first 4 posts (if there are 4, otherwise less), then "......" (no idea where that is coming from!" and then it repeats the same loop of the 1st 4 posts again. It doesn't do what I wanted it to do. You can see that issue here with only 1 related post: http://www.zoomingjapan.com/2011/172/ or here with actually 6 related posts, but only 4 are displayed+repeated as mentioned before: http://www.zoomingjapan.com/2011/lorem-ipsum-xd/. Why is this happening?

Comment: thanks for the link. your site looks very nice. i think we're nearly there now. none of the code on your pasted page should generate that `<div>....</div>` markup, but i notice you've now got some HTML comments in the output, so it looks as though your php file's changed? would you mind re-pasting? Otherwise the markup is as expected, it's just that scrollable is cloning your elements to create a 'circular' scroll effect - i think you can remove `{circular:true}` from `alltuts\js\scrollable.js` to stop this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Considering that most of the time I don't really know what I'm doing, I guess it looks quite okay :) I cannot spot any HTML code that could cause the "....." (I previously had something like that in there as placeholder but not anymore): http://pastebin.com/8WR49MAD Also, I set the circular to "false" but the problem still ocurrs, so it doesn't seem it's Scrollable that's causing it?!

Comment: So, the repeating issue seems to be solved, but it seems no more than 4 related posts will be shown with the current code. After 4 related posts, you'll get the "..." and then it's over. It worked fine when I had a complete loop in each scrollable div (I just used the same loop without offsets because I didn't know how to do it) and I got 4 divs with 4 related posts without any problem. Although it's not an elegant solution, maybe only that kind of code can live within scrollable? So, in each div we have to start a complete new loop and just offset it instead ... maybe.

Comment: ok, this is interesting. scrollable shouldn't mind how the divs are generated. it seems odd that you should only got four posts if your tags are appearing in others. would you mind putting in the line `<?php echo $my_query->post_count; ?>` just inside the loop? this will tell us how many posts the query is producing.

Comment: Hello again. I did. Please refer to the links I've posted in a previous comment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ok, thanks. that shows that it seems the problem is not with how it's being displayed - for some reason your query is not getting all the posts with the same tags. Perhaps you have some custom post types? these aren't included in the query by default, but it's easy to add them: underneath `'tag__in' => $tag_ids,`, add the line `'post_type' => 'any',` (don't forget the comma)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1621/discussion-between-djb-and-japanworm)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try the code from here [Show Related Post in WordPress](http://www.khapay.com/wordpress/show-related-post-wordpress.html)

I think you're not ending each query by

```
wp_reset_query();
```

Hope it helps.